# Iterating through a PHP array in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, foreach

How do I iterate through a PHP array in jQuery? I have an array in php named `$viewfields`.
How do I iterate through each element of this array using jQuery?

**EDIT 1**

```
<?php foreach ($viewfields as $view): ?>           

if(<?=$view['Attribute']['type'];?>=='text'||<?=$view['Attribute']['type'];?>=='number')
{ 
     $("<input id=input<?=$view['Attribute']['sequence_no'];?> type= 'text' style= 'width:<?=$view['Attribute']['size'];?>px' data-attr=<?=$view['Attribute']['type'];?> ></input><br>").appendTo("#fb_contentarea_col1down21 #<?=$view['Attribute']['sequence_no'];?>");
}
```

If i give

```
$.each(arrayfromPHP,function(i,elem){

}
```

how do I write the code for $view['Attribute']['type'] in jQuery?
elem['Attribute']['type'] won't work I suppose?

**EDIT 2**

elem['Attribute']['type'] does work

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($viewFields) ?>;

$.each(arrayFromPHP, function (i, elem) {
    // do your stuff
});
```

To better understand how the things are wired together (thanks Jonathan Sampson):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($viewFields) ?>;

$.each(arrayFromPHP, function (i, elem) {
    // do your stuff
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

You can of course place that `SCRIPT` tag wherever you want in the page, or you can even reference `arrayFromPHP` from external scripts as `arrayFromPHP` is declared as global.

#### EDIT

Given this PHP array:

```
$viewFields = array(
    'Attributes' => array(
        'type'  => 'foo',
        'label' => 'bar',
    ),
    'Attributes' => array(
        'type'  => 'foo',
        'label' => 'bar',
    ),
);
```

Accessing its elements with jQuery would be done like this:

```
// json_encode() will output:
// {"Attributes":{"type":"foo","label":"bar"}}

$.each(arrayFromPHP, function (i, elem) {
    alert(elem.type);
    alert(elem.label);
});
```

Comment: Note that PHP and jQuery aren't written side-by-side. You'll need to wrap the PHP in <?php and ?>, and the jQuery in <script type="text/javascript"> and </script.

Comment: In the php for array, I use the individual elements of the array as
$view['Attribute']['id'] or $view['Attribute']['label'], where I assign $view as <?php foreach($viewfields as $view):?>

how do I access those elements in .each function()?

Comment: @Angeline, can you edit the question and post the structure of the PHP array as returned by `print_r`? Just paste the output of `print_r($viewFields)`.

Comment: By the way, here's some documentation about `jQuery.each`: http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each

Comment: @lonut G.Stan : Thank you so much. I'm getting the answer.
but one small change, it's elem['Attribute']['type'] rather than elem.type. ;)

Answer (score -2):

The easily way is:

PHP:

```
$an_array=array();
$an_array[]='Element 1';
$an_array[]='Element 2';
$an_array[]='Element 3';
$array_js=implode(",",$this->js_pagina); //join elements in a string
```

JQUERY:

```
//Converter
window.array=new String('<?php echo $array_js?>');
window.array=window.js_pagina.split(",");
//Iterator
$.each(window.array, function (i, elem) 
{
        alert(elem);
});
```