# Adding information to a page at the end of a loop to show progress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a loop that runs through a text area's line and processes each line in a loop.

At the moment the page just stays frozen until all fo the data has been processed.

How can I make it so that as soon as a line has finished processing (when it loops back) it adds for instance "Line 1 processed" "Line 2 processed" etc so that the user can see that it is working.

I am using PHP and would like to use jquery as I am already using in on the site.

Thanks

Comment: you need to elaborate more on that...

Comment: the task basically takes a URL and pings it and returns its HTTP status code. I want to be able to see this working by showing each url and status code as it has processed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not specify any details, I'll just take a wild guess of what you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //get the textarea value
    var value = $('textarea#my_textarea').val();
    //split it into lines
    var lines = value.split('\n');
    //for every line
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        //call line_proccesser.php passing a line to it
        $.post(
             'line_proccesser.php',
             {line:lines[i]},
             function(){
                 //when script has worked, printing status info
                 $("#info").append('Line ' + (i+1) + 'processed<br />');
             }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 good answer, however, you might want to add that making an ajax request for every line is going to slow down things even more and is causing a lot of extra traffic (as opposed to one request).

Comment: @jeroen thank you. Yes, it will be slow, but since we do not know the task details, it's hard to guess whether it will be important or not.

Comment: that´s true. I´d probably just show that it´s working without giving specific progress details.

Answer (score 0):

sorry didn't read your question properly the first time..

perhaps this would help [Iterating through a PHP array in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205892/iterating-through-a-php-array-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ajax to process your request, it will not generate any feedback until all processing has finished so you can either:

1. use @Silver Light's solution and split the request in multiple requests (has disadvantages);
2. settle for something like a modal overlay (dimming the page) and displaying a spinning wheel to show the user that it is working.