# jquery iterate through nested object

Tags: jquery

I´m getting data from php. which I parse to JSON

```
var d = $.parseJSON(returnData);
```

d.designer looks like:

```
[Object, Object, Object] 

0: Object
_id: 1 
family: null
firstname: "XX"
lastname: "YY"
__proto__: Object

1: Object
_id: 2 
family: null
firstname: "XX"
lastname: "YY"
__proto__: Object

2: Object
_id: 5 
family: null
firstname: "XX"
lastname: "YY"
__proto__: Object
```

With jquery how can I loop trough objects to get:

```
Id: 1
Id: 2
ID: 5
```

where ID value is key _id ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating through a PHP array in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205892/iterating-through-a-php-array-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use each that return value and key for every element

```
$.each(d, function( index, value ) {
  console.log("ID: "+index);
});
```

Comment: that´s it thanks. I changed it a bit to fit: $.each(d.designer, function( index, value ) { console.log("ID: "+index+" = " +value._id); …